# How to make a custom generator which also generates a migration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator

Here I have a custom generator that I'm making. I also need my custom generator to generate a migration with some prefilled values (i.e., a migration template)

Here is my generator file:

```
class BlockGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  source_root File.expand_path('templates', __dir__)
  argument :model, type: :string

  def generate_model
    generate_block_model
  end

  private
  def generate_block_model
    template 'block_model_controller_template.template', "app/controllers/garcia_cms/#{model.pluralize.underscore}_controller.rb"
    template 'block_model_template.template', "app/models/#{model.singularize.underscore}.rb"
  end
end
```

I know that I need to add this line in order to use a migration template.

`migration_template "migration.rb", "db/migrate/add_foo_to_bar.rb"`

But whenever I try to use my generator with that line placed in my `generate_block_model` method, I always get an error that says

```
undefined method `migration_template' for #<BlockGenerator:0x00007f830cd155b0> (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the [Rails::Generators::Migration](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/Migration.html) module:

```
class BlockGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  include Rails::Generators::Migration
  source_root File.expand_path('templates', __dir__)
  argument :model, type: :string

  def generate_model
    generate_block_model
  end

  private
  def generate_block_model
    template 'block_model_controller_template.template', "app/controllers/garcia_cms/#{model.pluralize.underscore}_controller.rb"
    template 'block_model_template.template', "app/models/#{model.singularize.underscore}.rb"
    migration_template "migration.rb", "db/migrate/add_foo_to_bar.rb"
  end
end
```